# Initialize form with request.user in a ModelForm django and hide that value

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a problem when populating the form, I want to initial the form with request.user and hide that value ! I try to use it but appear an error :

"IntegrityError at /create

NOT NULL constraint failed: auctions_listings.listed_by_id"

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Categories(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"

class Listings(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categories, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_tag')
    listed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title} {self.description} {self.price} {self.image_url} {self.category}"
```

forms.py

```
class NewListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Listings
        exclude = ['listed_by']
```

views.py

```
def create(request):
    user = request.user.username
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewListingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Created Success')
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
                "form":form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": NewListingForm(initial={'listed_by': user})
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to initialize the form with the value. From what I understand you just want to set `listed_by` to the current user. You can do this by setting `request.user` to `form.instance.listed_by` if the form is valid:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = NewListingForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.listed_by = request.user
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,'Created Success')
            # Successful form save should end in a redirect!
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
                "form":form
            })
    return render(request, "auctions/create.html", {
        "form": NewListingForm()
    })
```

I assume that you use the `login_required` decorator to ensure that the user is logged in. If not please do so.